# Click Events in phantom js do not always fire

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, capybara

I am having an issue where a click event is not firing (sometimes it will, other times it will not), this always happens when running the browser in a headless state.

I will use the `.click` method like so

```
find("#peoplePreview > tbody > tr:first-of-type > td > a").click
```

When running phantomjs in debug mode i get

```
"name":"find","args":["css","#peoplePreview > tbody > tr:first-of-type > td > a"]}
{"response":{"page_id":18,"ids":[10]}}
{"name":"click","args":[18,10]}
{"response":{"position":{"x":114,"y":523.5}}}
```

So as far as i can see the element has been found and the element clicked at the correct coordinates, yet the event is not fired

Anyone come across this or have an alternative to get this event to fire?

This is how I have setup poltergeist

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless do |app|
  options = {
  :js_errors => false,
  :inspector => true,
  :debug => true,
  :path => '/usr/bin/',
  :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any']
 }
 Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: POST THE FULL CODE PLEASE, (normally you should call the click method like this  `...td > a").click();`)

Comment: Could be a bug in PhantomJS with the `:first-of-type` selector. Try using XPath instead of CSS selectors and try not to specifically write for "tbody".

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that happen to me several times... I always narrowed it down to some timing issue. My suspicion is that the element is present and clickable but not fully loaded, so when clicking it does not trigger the event it should...

The workaround to keep my headless tests consistent was adding sleeps or attempting to click an element in a loop until the expected outcome of the ".click" event is achieved.

For example:

```
10.times do
  sleep 0.5
  element.click
  break if some_other_element[:disabled].nil? #result if the initial click was successful
end
```

It was a very funky solution but was the only reliable one I found...